# Spreadsheetgears charts with multiple ranges as source

Tags: c#, charts, spreadsheetgear

I have a problem when creating charts with Spreadsheetgears. I have a table with a bunch of columns and 3 rows:

[image: Table]

I need to create 3 charts with Spreadsheetgears for each row with the week names as category labels:

[image: Series 1]

[image: Series 2]

[image: Series 3]

But while these charts are easy to generate by selecting two different ranges and then inserting a chart, for example, row 1 and row 4, Spreadsheetgears does not support multiple ranges for the `SetDataSource` method.

So the question is, how do you create charts that look at different ranges in one table?

Do you create the charts with one range and then set the category labels afterwards? How does one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague came up with a workaround. The solution is to create all three charts with the whole table as the data source, and then remove the unwanted series from each chart. Simple.